# Multi Column CASE WHEN in Teradata

Tags: sql, teradata

I'm trying to consolidate a few sub-queries to avoid hitting a massive table (42B rows) multiple times and getting

> "[3771] Illegal Expression in WHEN clause of CASE expression."

```
,SUM(CASE
    WHEN (oh.LOCN_NBR,oh.WK_NBR) IN (SELECT LOCN_NBR,START_WK FROM VT_STORES)
    THEN oh.TTL_UN_QT
    ELSE NULL
    END) AS BEGINNING_OH
```

Is there any way to do multi-column IN statements within a CASE statement, or am I stuck putting these in the join/where in a subquery as it is currently?

Edit: Full Query as requested:

```
SELECT
            oh.LOCN_NBR AS LOCN_NBR
            ,item.ITEM_ID AS ITEM_ID
            ,SUM(CASE
                WHEN oh.WK_NBR = (SELECT WK_NBR FROM ALEX_ARP_VIEWS_PRD.REF_CUSTOM_TIME WHERE cust_time_id=2 )
                THEN oh.TTL_UN_QT
                ELSE NULL 
            END) AS SALEABLE_QTY
            ,SUM(CASE
                WHEN oh.WK_NBR = (SELECT LY_WK_NBR FROM ALEX_ARP_VIEWS_PRD.REF_CUSTOM_TIME WHERE cust_time_id=2 )
                THEN oh.TTL_UN_QT
                ELSE NULL 
            END) AS SALEABLE_QTY_LY
            ,SUM(CASE
                WHEN (oh.LOCN_NBR,oh.WK_NBR) IN (SELECT LOCN_NBR,PRI_START_WK FROM VT_STORES)
                THEN oh.TTL_UN_QT
                ELSE NULL
            END) AS BEGINNING_OH_LY
            ,SUM(CASE
                WHEN (oh.LOCN_NBR,oh.WK_NBR) IN (SELECT LOCN_NBR,START_WK FROM VT_STORES)
                THEN oh.TTL_UN_QT
                ELSE NULL
            END) AS BEGINNING_OH

FROM 
            ALEX_ARP_VIEWS_PRD.FACT_WKLY_OPR_INS oh
            INNER JOIN VT_STORES stores ON oh.LOCN_NBR = stores.LOCN_NBR
            INNER JOIN VT_ITEM item ON oh.VEND_PACK_ID = item.VEND_PACK_ID
WHERE               
            INS_TYP_CD='H'
            AND TTL_UN_QT <> 0
            AND WK_NBR >= (SELECT MIN(PRI_START_WK) FROM VT_STORES)
GROUP BY
    oh.LOCN_NBR
    ,item.ITEM_ID
```

Comment: What's the key of `VT_STORES`?

Comment: locn_nbr is the key of VT_STORES

Comment: Do the logic of the query requires to read all the 42B rows,  or you would expect some of the where condition to restrict the number significatively? If so,  from the plan you see this restriction works? As a curiosity, is the large table composed only from the 5-6 fields we see or it has lots of additional columns? And you need to do all the logic in a single query or you might use some steps in temporary/volatile tables?

Comment: The biggest problem is that the INS_TYPE_CD column is not indexed, and there is no way I am going to be able to convince the DBAs to change the structure of this table given its size and importance - this eliminates about 50% of the data in the table right away. I would be more than open to other solutions, but everything I have tried in regards to temp/vt blows through my spool limit (100G).

Comment: With 50%, I don't think an index would do such a big difference.  Maybe a partition would be more useful.  However,  if you can't even put the data in a vt/gtt, I'm afraid that you really need to increase your spool.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `IN`.  You can use `exists`:

```
SUM(CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM VT_STORES v WHERE oh.LOCN_NBR = v.LOCN_NBR AND oh.WK_NBR = v.START_WK)
        THEN oh.TTL_UN_QT
     END) AS BEGINNING_OH
```

However, I'm not 100% sure the problem is the `IN`.  Many databases do not allow subqueries as arguments to aggregation functions.  I'm not sure if Teradata allows this functionality.

Comment: I have added the full query as requested (in its non working state). If I comment out the third and fourth case functions, the query works, so subqueries are allowed... it just appears to be the multi-column portion that isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to consolidate a few sub-queries to avoid hitting a massive table multiple times

Multi-column Subqueries are only allowed in `WHERE`, but not in `CASE`. Rewriting to `EXISTS` will not probably not improve performance, the plan might actually be more complex.

You simply try hiding complexity, but it's still an Outer Join in the background, like this:

```
,Sum(CASE WHEN stores.LOCN_NBR IS NOT NULL THEN oh.TTL_UN_QT END) AS BEGINNING_OH
...
FROM oh LEFT JOIN 
 (
   SELECT LOCN_NBR,START_WK FROM VT_STORES
 ) AS stores
 ON stores.LOCN_NBR = oh.LOCN_NBR
AND stores.START_WK  = oh.WK_NBR
```

Can you show your current query (at least those parts you try to optimize)?

**Edit:**

When VT_STORES.locn_nbr is unique this should return the same result:

```
SELECT
            oh.LOCN_NBR AS LOCN_NBR
            ,item.ITEM_ID AS ITEM_ID
            ,Sum(CASE
                WHEN oh.WK_NBR = (SELECT Min(WK_NBR) FROM ALEX_ARP_VIEWS_PRD.REF_CUSTOM_TIME WHERE cust_time_id=2 )
                THEN oh.TTL_UN_QT
                ELSE NULL 
            END) AS SALEABLE_QTY
            ,Sum(CASE
                WHEN oh.WK_NBR = (SELECT Min(LY_WK_NBR) FROM ALEX_ARP_VIEWS_PRD.REF_CUSTOM_TIME WHERE cust_time_id=2 )
                THEN oh.TTL_UN_QT
                ELSE NULL 
            END) AS SALEABLE_QTY_LY
            ,Sum(CASE
                WHEN oh.WK_NBR= stores.PRI_START_WK 
                THEN oh.TTL_UN_QT
            END) AS BEGINNING_OH_LY
            ,Sum(CASE
                WHEN oh.WK_NBR = stores.START_WK 
                THEN oh.TTL_UN_QT
            END) AS BEGINNING_OH

FROM 
            ALEX_ARP_VIEWS_PRD.FACT_WKLY_OPR_INS oh
            INNER JOIN VT_STORES stores ON oh.LOCN_NBR = stores.LOCN_NBR
            INNER JOIN VT_ITEM item ON oh.VEND_PACK_ID = item.VEND_PACK_ID
WHERE               
            INS_TYP_CD='H'
            AND TTL_UN_QT <> 0
            AND WK_NBR >= (SELECT Min(PRI_START_WK) FROM VT_STORES)
GROUP BY
    oh.LOCN_NBR
    ,item.ITEM_ID
```

The other Scalar Subqueries should be fine, because they return only a single row and the optimizer knows that.

Comment: I have added the full query as requested (in its non working state). If I comment out the third and fourth case functions, the query works, so subqueries are allowed... it just appears to be the multi-column portion that isn't working.

Comment: This works, but unfortunately results in me hitting spool space limitations now. I think I've settled upon consolidating what used to be 4 queries (each SUM operation) down to 2 queries - the first two, and then the second two. Thanks for your help - I was overcomplicating the issue with the case statement.

Comment: You should check Explain if there's something bad in it. The Scalar Subqueries should show as a Dispatcher Retrieve Step or be based on Incremental Plannig. You might have to talk to your DBA to increase spool...

Answer (score 0):

re: *Is there any way to do multi-column IN statements within a CASE statement*

no.

re: *to avoid hitting a massive table (42B rows) multiple times*

which one is large?  I don't see how, even if a compound `IN` clause worked, you would avoid hitting a large table multiple times compared to using a join/adding columns to a `where` clause.

have you tried something like:

```
SELECT
    ...
        ,SUM(CASE
            WHEN SELECT COUNT(*) FROM VT_STORES 
                 WHERE LOCN_NBR = oh.LOCN_NBR AND 
                 PRI_START_WK = oh.WK_NBR > 1
                 THEN oh.TTL_UN_QT
            END) AS BEGINNING_OH_LY
        ,SUM(CASE
             WHEN SELECT COUNT(*) FROM VT_STORES 
                  WHERE LOCN_NBR = oh.LOCN_NBR AND 
                  START_WK = oh.WK_NBR > 1
                  THEN oh.TTL_UN_QT
             END) AS BEGINNING_OH
        FROM 
            ...
```

?

If it's `VT_STORES` that's large, try:

```
ALEX_ARP_VIEWS_PRD.FACT_WKLY_OPR_INS oh INNER JOIN 
(select
   LOCN_NBR,
   PRI_START_WK,
   START_WK
 from
   VT_STORES) stores ON 
oh.LOCN_NBR = stores.LOCN_NBR and
(PRI_START_WK = oh.WK_NBR OR
START_WK = oh.WK_NBR)
```

although I've seen performance hits from using `OR` clauses in joins, you might be better off with two inner joins, one for each week you want.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more specific in my question - the large table is the ALEX_ARP_VIEWS_PRD.FACT_WKLY_OPR_INS table. The original design had each SUM operation as its own distinct query.